# Expand a start/end interval entry into separate rows using LINQ/EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, projection

Given an object (or data row, in SQL terms) representing a range of numbers, with `Start` and `End` properties, how do I "expand" those numbers into actual individual units using LINQ in a way that is translatable to EFCore?

This is easy to do in memory with an iterator:

```cs
for (var number = range.Start; number <= range.End; number++)
    yield return number;
```

But of course I can't do this with a queryable, since iterating on the original query already goes into the database.

How do I achieve the same behavior while doing this in the database? Say I have a `IQueryable<Range>` and wanted to convert it into a `IQueryable<int>`, where for each range, the resulting query would contain all individual entries in the range as separate rows.

I found a few examples of [how to achieve this directly in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494219/sql-expanding-a-row-with-start-end-into-individual-rows) but I wanted to make sure it was possible to do it using LINQ operators and in a way that EF could interpret into the appropriate SQL statement.

Can something like this be coded without using an iterator?

Comment: Try  Enumerable.Range(start, count).Select(x =>

Comment: You can't do this with LINQ to EF Core. You need to do something in SQL or create in-memory and upload to database.

Comment: I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583359/10646316) may help

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for the link, but I'm not sure how it does. The example you provided needs to generate all the values in memory to them be able to use them in the query, but in my scenario the generation itself needs to happen in the database as the values used as parameters for the generation are part of each of the rows on the data itself. Does your library also support that scenario?

Comment: If you find SQL function which can do that, then yes.

Comment: If you create a numbers table of integers, or table-valued function that returns integers within the specified range, you can join that table with your range limits.